# php text file read and out put display on browser

Tags: php, file

i have txt file assume go.txt its a log file and contents adding dynamically to the file .

i want read it using php and display on browser  in each minute any help

thanks in advance 
roshan

Comment: So what have you came up with so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could easily put a softlink on this file and put that one in your htdocs folder. Well depends on your webserver and configuration. So you don't have to use php to read it.

If you don't want that, you can make use of the php function [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php), this will just dump the file's contents to stdout.

```
<?php
   echo file_get_contents(filePathToLogFile);
?>
```

You'll have to let the client poll to update the page. This can be achieved with javascript. Something like this could do the work:

```
refreshPage();
setInterval("refreshPage()", 60000);
function refreshPage() {
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: I think you're just looking for `setTimeout(window.location.reload, 60000)` for your Javascript. As it is now it's more verbose than necessary and will also immediately reload the page.